# Windows phone: как сделать автоматический скролл страницы?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Добавляю динамически на страницу новые элементы. При этом если они не помещаются и уползают вниз, то я не могу до них добраться, так как скроллинг не работает. Как его включить?

Comment: Вы хотите просто включить скроллинг или хотите сделать так, чтобы он автоматически позиционировался на новых элементах?

Comment: У меня есть StackPanel и в ней по нажатию кнопки добавляются новые TextBox-ы. Когда их становится много, они уползают за границы страницы и до них не добраться. Для этого мне нужно как-то задействовать прокрутку, или всей страницы или только внутри этой StackPanel, как вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поместите свой `StackPanel` в `ScrollViewer` и настройте видимость его скроллбаров как вам требуется.